# Library Dart Packages has broken classes paths:

Tags: flutter, android-studio, package

I'm facing an issue in my Project structure where some of my used packages have a broken path. I already tried `dart pub cache repair` but the error remains.

[image]

Comment: Try clear cache and rebuild. In Android studio its file->invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.pub-cache` file from directory that located.

Answer (score -1):

This is what fixed it for me. : "Remove Invalid Roots" in the Project Structure -> Problems

[image]